# converting std::string to int using sstream

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, sstream

I'm trying to convert a string of an arbitrary length to an int but so far it works only for strings of limited length. Code so far:

```
long long convertToInt (std::string x){
   long long number;
   std::istringstream ss(x);
   ss >> number;
   return number;}
```

for `x=100000000000000000000000001` the function returns `0`. Could someone explain why? Thanks.

Comment: what do you want it to return?

Comment: even `long long` is too short for `100000000000000000000000001`

Comment: Needs long long long.

Comment: You might want to check out a library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: @Melanie I want to return an int represented by the string

Comment: @RetiredNinja, But long long long is too long for GCC.

Comment: @Maddy: you mean parse it?

Comment: Unless you're privy to a 128-bit extended unsigned long platform, I'm not seeing this happening. And those don't come easy, but if you have one your limit reaches 340282366920938463463374607431768211455. If not, time to break out a bignum lib.

Comment: @Melanie just convert the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inbuilt integer types your compiler provides are only guaranteed to be capable of storing numbers of a specific magnitude.  It looks like your number is larger than that.  You may find the C++ program is reporting the error - try...

```
if (ss >> number)
    return number;
throw std::runtime_error("conversion of string to int failed");
```

...or whatever other error handling you feel like.

If you must use larger number, you could try `double`, or if that doesn't suit your needs then check out "arbitrary precision" libraries like GMP - you'll find lots of stackoverflow questions about handling large numbers with answers suggesting, contrasting and illustrating GMP and alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

The value `"100000000000000000000000001"` is to large to fit in a `long long` (or `unsigned long long`) so the extraction fails.

Use [`numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to determine the maximum value for types in your implementation:

```
#include <limits>

std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() << "\n";
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() << "\n";
std::cout << "100000000000000000000000001\n";
```

prints:

```
18446744073709551615
9223372036854775807
100000000000000000000000001
```

Check the result of the extraction attempt to ensure extraction occurred:

```
if (ss >> number)
{
    return number;
}
// Report failure.
```

Comment: So what return type do I specify If I want the function to handle strings of arbitrary length?

Comment: @maddy, The one described in the link in the comment.

Comment: @maddy, there might be some big integer libraries around that may support what your require but I am unfamiliar with them.

Comment: http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers

Comment: @maddy that one is better ;) http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-General